# Remove comma in coldfusion string

Tags: coldfusion, escaping, xss

I am using,

```
#replaceList(oe.sql,";,&,<,>,`,',!,@,$,%,(,),=,+,{,},[,],\","")#
```

to remove unwanted characters from user input.

My problem is, that when I try all forbidden characters in the input-field replacelist removes every unwanted sign but leaves every comma there.

```
;,&,<,>,`,',!,@,$,%,(,),=,+,{,},[,],\ --> ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Does anyone know how to remove this? I tried:

`,,,`  and   `,[^,],`  in the "filter-string" and none of these worked...

```
#replace(#replaceList(oe.sql,";,&,<,>,`,',!,@,$,%,(,),=,+,{,},[,],\","")#,",","", "All")#
```

did also not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [REReplace](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_35.html) or [REReplaceNoCase](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_35.html) functions to remove unwanted characters (specified as regular expression) from a string:

```
#REReplace(";,&,<,>,`,',!,@,$,%,(,),=,+,{,},[,],\", "[;&<>`'!@$%()=+{}[\]\\,""]*", "", "ALL")#
```

`ReplaceList` function is useful in case if you need to replace certain values from one list with corresponding values from another.

Comment: Just add double quotation mark in regular expression and escape it with additional `"` mark: `[;&<>``'!@$%()=+{}[\]\\,""]*`

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the empty list elements like this:

```
NewList = ArrayToList(ListToArray(OldList));
```

Comment: Struct-ify it...I see but you should also give him the reverse so he can recombine (if necessary in the OPs case). Plus +1

Comment: Using `listChangeDelims()` is probably a more expedient operation here, and also closer to the intent of what the desired operation. That said, it'd be much better to suggest a solution which didn't leave the dangling cruft in the first place.

Comment: listChangeDelims() seems most easy to implement, as I was so studip to not check if the function works before writing it everywhere... Can I use it like this? `#listChangeDelims(#replaceList(form.whatever,";,&,<,>,`,',,,!,@,$,%,(,),=,+,{,},[,],\","")#),"0"#"`     Because this always throws an error

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code-formatting... I've now seen the four spaces instead of using ``